# icon is not in 3.00 format

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, icons

When building a C++ application in Visual Studio 2008, I receive the following error: iconfile.ico is not in 3.00 format.

I created the icon file using Paint, and saved it as a .ico file.

I tried saving it as 16 bit, 24 bit, and 256 color.

So far, none of these formats appear to be version 3.00.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Why is this question tagged "C++" & "Visual Studio 2008"? Any environment will emit this error, when loading incorrect icons, I guess...

Comment: I tagged it this way because that is where the issue cropped up. I am supposing that a different IDE or language, might give more information in the error message. I did not test/validate it with any other language or IDE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I downloaded this:[Photo Filtre](http://photofiltre.en.softonic.com/)
I had to convert the file to  a .ico file. I had assumed that if I do a "save as", it did more than just change the extension. After the conversion, the icon worked correctly.

Answer (score 2):

try using a third party tool to open and resave the icon, e.g. icofx.  (www.icofx.ro)

Comment: That is what I did. I already had the answer, I was just posting it here because I did not find a solid answer anywhere else.